# pass an asset file from one service to another

Tags: android, android-intent, assets

I have got a service, which should be made generic by using data files provided by other services (providers). I prefer the providers to be as simple as possible, and the data they provide should be stored in asset files. Data will be constant and only be read once by the client.

Because I have no experience with 'intent' or 'contentProviders' I would like suggestions on which way to go.

More specific:

Is ContentProviders too complicated for this ? The samples I looked at were all using databases.

Is it possible to pass a sort of file pointer to an asset file from one service to another, or do the provider have to read its asset file and pass the data to the client in an object ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Pass an "asset" around? What about putting it into an intent extras?

Comment: How can I put an asset into intent extras ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access asset files like this. Try this if i am correct "file:///android_asset/fileName"